# How create realistic semi gloss paint shader?

Tags: shaders, photorealism

How do I recreate the green surface shader?
Just the green parts, not the decals. I tried mixing a green diffuse and glossy shader with a layer weight node as the factor. Yet, I'm not able to get that surface.
[image]

**UPDATE : **
 using @LukeD 's solution I got it to this stage but it's not dark enough.
[image]

Comment: Maybe you would be Interested in [these Videos from BlenderGuru](https://youtu.be/V3wghbZ-Vh4?list=PLtdRSLIE6gB3OGyh9D0iF2yL-67c6olKB).
He shows how to make PBR Shaders for Dielectic and Metalic Materials(Metalic = part 2). you can download his version of the Shaders or build them yourself while watching him.
I would recommend the second.. you know what each part of the shader will do afterwards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Final:

[image: final]

### Overview:

Material itself is pretty simple even without using complicated PBR (but you can try it of course - look for CynicatPro) but the devil lays in details which are **Bumps** in this case.

You should work on them, as they are different for different parts of the Tank. Also **Roughness map** would be a good idea. Some parts are shinier then others.

This setup is just **Diffuse** mixed with **Glossy** by **Fresnel** and with procedural **Bump Map**.

You can try to use texture for bumps, same goes with roughness map.

Comment: I tried your method, but I got odd results

Comment: Check node setup carefully. I'll upload blend file later. It's impossible to have so much differences.

Comment: it was the HDRI, I set it at a higher brightness value, my bad XD